# Let n be a positive integer such that

Tags: trigonometry, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

$\sin {\frac {π}{2n}}+\cos {\frac {π}{2n}}=\frac{\sqrt n}{2}$. Then

A) $6\le n\le8$,     B) $4\lt n\le8$,

C) $4\le n\le 8$,    D)  $4 \lt n\lt8$,

I couldn't get started in solving it. That's why I asked help

Comment: Of course if any of the answers is correct then C is also correct

Comment: There are only 4 values of $n$ involved, so you can just plug them in, one by one and see for which of them the equality holds and for which it doesn't. Sometimes the most stupid, most boring brute force approaches are the best. This is one of those occasions.

Comment: In other words: don't solve, just check

Comment: @Vincent and that is where the confusion gets even bigger: If I'm not wrong, the only solution is $n=6$. This is a subset of each of the four options, but not equal to any of them. I interpret this so that each answer is valid (i..e, not only does the text explicitely say "If ... then", but in fact the question *cannot* be meant to read "if and only if")

Answer (score 2):

Given $\sin\dfrac{\pi}{2n}+\cos\dfrac{\pi}{2n}=\dfrac{\sqrt n}{2}$

$\left(\sin\dfrac{\pi}{2n}+\cos\dfrac{\pi}{2n}\right)^2 = \left(\dfrac{\sqrt n}{2}\right)^2$

$\sin^2\dfrac{\pi}{2n}+\cos^2\dfrac{\pi}{2n}+2\sin\dfrac{\pi}{2n}\cos\dfrac{\pi}{2n}=\dfrac{n}{4}$

$1+\sin\dfrac{\pi}{n}=\dfrac{n}{4}$

$\sin\dfrac{\pi}{n}=\dfrac{n-4}{4}$

Since $-1\le\sin\theta\le1$

$\dfrac{n-4}{4}\le1$

$n\le8$

Also, $\dfrac{n-4}{4}\ge0$

$n\ge4$

So, we have $4\le n\le8$

Now lets check whether it satisfies $\sin\dfrac{\pi}{n}=\dfrac{n-4}{4}$

Lets take $n=4$ and we get that $\sin\dfrac{\pi}{4}\ne0$

and for $n=8$ we get that $$\sin\dfrac{\pi}{8}\ne1$$

Therefore, the answer is $4<n<8$

Comment: For $\pi>t>0,$ $$1<1+\sin2t\le2$$ that precludes $4$

Comment: Thanks that really helped 

Answer (score 1):

By C-S $$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}=\sin\frac{\pi}{2n}+\cos\frac{\pi}{2n}\leq\sqrt{(1+1)(\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2n}+\cos^2\frac{\pi}{2n})}=\sqrt2,$$
which gives $n\leq8.$

The equality does not occur, which says $n<8.$

Also, by squaring easy to see that $n>4,$ which gives the answer:
$$4<n<8.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let  $$f(x)=\sin  x+\cos x=2\sin\tfrac\pi 4\cos (x-\tfrac\pi 4)=\sqrt 2 \cos(x-\tfrac\pi 4).$$
(Brush up on trigonometric addition theorems!)
and 
$$ g(n)=f(\tfrac\pi{2n}).$$

We are lookoing for positive integer solutions of $$\tag1g(n)=\frac{\sqrt n}2.$$
As $g(1)=\sqrt 2\cos\frac\pi4=1\ne\frac{\sqrt 2}2$ and $g(2)=\sqrt 2\cos 0=\sqrt 2\ne\frac{\sqrt 2}2$, we need only cosider $n$ with $n>2$. In that range, $g$ is a strictly decreasing function of $n$ because $f$ is strictly increasing on $(0,\frac{\pi}{4})$.
As the right hand side of $(1)$ is strictly increasing as a function of $n$, we conclude that $(1)$ has at most one solution in positive integers.
Incidentally, $$g(6)=\sqrt 2\cos\left(\frac\pi{12}-\frac\pi4\right)=\sqrt 2\cos\frac\pi6=\sqrt 2\cdot\frac{\sqrt 3}2=\frac{\sqrt 6}2$$
so that we can conclude:

> The equation $\sin\frac\pi{2n}+\cos\frac \pi{2n}=\frac{\sqrt n}2$ has exactly one solution in positive integers, namely $n=6$.

The condition thus found is strictly stronger than each of the given options A,B,C,D.

*Remark:* Even if we allow $n$ to be any positive real, this would not introduce any additional solutions.